# Progress icons with sum in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I have a basic sheet with monthly stats. For the end of each month, there are totals.

I want to clearly show if there was an increase or decrease next to the sum for each month. Ideally, with a green or red arrow next to the sum for each month.

Is there a way to show an increase or decrease between my monthly total values?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use conditional formatting icon sets. Is it one month per sheet? Are the totals on the same row every month?

Comment: @DickKusleika I have used conditional formatting as you suggested and edited the rules to show arrows appropriately. Thank you for your suggestion, all sorted.